# Redirect in a callback of type MENU_CALLBACK

Tags: redirect, drupal-6

Why doesn't `drupal_goto()` work in my menu callback?

```
function _mymodule_mycallback() {
  global $user;

  $nid = arg(1);
  // needed for node_object_prepare
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); // needed for node_object_prepare()     
  $new_node = (object) array();
  $new_node->type  = 'auction';
  $new_node->language = '';

  node_object_prepare($new_node);
  node_save($new_node);
  $new_nid = $new_node->nid;

  drupal_goto('node/'.$new_nid, drupal_get_destination()); 

  exit();
}
```

I always get back to the calling site. I already tried `url()` and sending headers but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

try an `unset($_REQUEST['destination']);` (and possibly also an `unset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination'])` before the call to `drupal_goto()` if latter doesn't seem to work.

***UPDATE END***

try just

```
drupal_goto("node/$new_nid");
```

(without `drupal_get_destination();` also the `exit();` is superfluous - see [the doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6))